# Mac Freezes on Launch

Tags: startup, crash, performance, launchd, login

Mac running `10.14.5` is freezing after the login screen each time I reboot. Seeing these stange messages in `/var/log/system.log` that seems suspect. `com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[471]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.` consistently shows up in the logs each time I reboot. The timeframe of the messages in the excerpt below matches the time the system is unresponsive, sometimes it never stops beach balling.

This has been an issue for some time, across several os releases.

Any idea what might be causing this/possible fix?

```
Aug 21 11:46:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[442]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[442]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Aug 21 11:46:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[446]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[446]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[470]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[470]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[471]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[471]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[472]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[472]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:45 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[474]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Aug 21 11:46:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[473]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[473]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[480]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[480]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.2933313A-3E84-4039-A768-9A426C51DB79[415]): Caller wanted oneshot behavior for pre-existing instance: caller = Finder
Aug 21 11:47:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[481]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[481]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[509]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[509]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[511]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[472]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:45 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[474]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Aug 21 11:46:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[473]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[473]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[480]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[480]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.2933313A-3E84-4039-A768-9A426C51DB79[415]): Caller wanted oneshot behavior for pre-existing instance: caller = Finder
Aug 21 11:47:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[481]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[481]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[509]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[509]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[511]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[442]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[442]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Aug 21 11:46:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[446]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[446]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[470]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[470]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[471]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[471]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[472]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[472]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:46:45 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[474]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Aug 21 11:46:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[473]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:46:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[473]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[480]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[480]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.2933313A-3E84-4039-A768-9A426C51DB79[415]): Caller wanted oneshot behavior for pre-existing instance: caller = Finder
Aug 21 11:47:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[481]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[481]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[509]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[509]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[511]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:30 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[511]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[512]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[512]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:47:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[514]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:47:50 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[514]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:48:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.A518D1AA-F83A-4F1C-9BBD-B88843476EC7[447]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:48:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.A518D1AA-F83A-4F1C-9BBD-B88843476EC7[447]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:48:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[515]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:48:00 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[515]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:48:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[519]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:48:10 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[519]): Extension did not initialize in time.
Aug 21 11:48:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[542]): Extension is hanging on launch. Killing.
Aug 21 11:48:20 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider[542]): Extension did not initialize in time.
```

Thanks

Comment: Will it boot up in Safe Mode (hold Shift when pressing the power button while powering on the machine)?

Comment: Same issues in safe mode

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting is often a process of elimination and does require patience, so you'll need to keep that in mind as you proceed.

The first thing I would do now is test your Mac in Safe Mode.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window
5. Now log into your Mac and see if it still freezes in Safe Mode (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Once again, test to see if your Mac still freezes when logging in normally

If you find that your Mac logs in fine while in Safe Mode, but not when booted normally, then it's likely to be a login item, corrupted font, or kernel extension.

If you find that your Mac still freezes in Safe Mode, then it's most likely a hardware problem.

**Investigating login items, fonts, and kernel extensions**

Let's start with Login Items:

1. Startup normally
2. Go to System Preferences > Users & Groups
3. Select the Login Items tab
4. Take a note of your Login Items
5. Now remove all of them by highlighting them and clicking on the <kbd>-</kbd> button below
6. Restart your Mac

Now your Mac will boot up without those login items loading. Test to see if you can use your Mac without it freezing:

- If you can, you know one (or more) of the Login items were causing the problem. You can then add them back in one by one until you've identified the culprit. Problem solved.
- If the problem does persist, it's either a problem with fonts you've installed yourself or with a 3rd party kernel extension. A little more info below:

**Fonts:-** You can remove any of the fonts you've installed yourself to see if this makes a difference.

**Kernel Extensions:-** You can open Terminal (found within your Utilites folder) and enter the following command:

`kextstat | grep -v com.apple`

The above command will list 3rd party kernel extensions (you may need to stretch the Terminal window so it's easier to read). Look for anything you don't remember installing, or something that belongs to software you've removed, or just anything that looks out of place. Remember though, this is a list of **3rd party kernel extensions** and therefore any of them could be causing the problem.

Comment: probably should have mentioned the same thing happens in safe mode, a clean reinstall solves the issue (do not think it is a hardware issue), but always re-appears later on, only non-apple kernel extension is [LittleSnitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)

Comment: Hmm, what model Mac are you running? And how much free space do you have on your boot volume?

Comment: Running a Macbook Pro 15" 2018, got around 100GB free disk space